# How can i create a button that can toggle sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to create a button that can toggle the sidebar
but I don't understand how to do it
I have already created the sidebar and the button
What should I do
Help!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header row ">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div id="logo" class="pb-2 ps-2 pe-0 col-2">
      <img class="float-start py-2 ps-2 pe-2" src="assets/img/unknown.png">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggler flex-shrink-0" id="menu-toggle">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left py-4 pe-2"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="body row ">
  <div class="sidebar col-2 " id="sidebar">
    <!--sidebar start-->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-laptop me-2"></i>Admin</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-transparent border-0">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">A</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">B</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">C</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-th me-2"></i>Cập nhật PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-keyboard me-2"></i>Phân loại PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar me-2"></i>Ước tính rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Cập nhật rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Báo cáo</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Tra cứu thông tin</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Hướng dẫn sử dụng</a>
    </div>
    <!--sidebar end-->
  </div>
  <div class="content col-10"> Content
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60bf89e922.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: actually, you don't really need a button but a checkbox. For bootstrap you can use a toggle switch (which is also based on an checkbox: https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/

Comment: @RandomCoder what do you need his CSS for? He uses a Framework (Bootstrap-5). Besides that, using `onclick` is a poor recommendation. An `eventListener` would be more appropriate but also not needed within a framework that can do it on its own by adding the correct classes.

Comment: You were also missing a </div> in your header

Comment: I want to create a button that can hide and also open the sidebar 
I know that the button gonna relate to js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header row ">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div id="logo" class="pb-2 ps-2 pe-0 col-2">
      <img class="float-start py-2 ps-2 pe-2" src="assets/img/unknown.png">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggler flex-shrink-0" id="menu-toggle">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left py-4 pe-2"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="body row ">
  <div class="sidebar col-2 " id="sidebar">
    <!--sidebar start-->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <div class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-laptop me-2"></i>Admin</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu bg-transparent border-0">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">A</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">B</a>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">C</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-th me-2"></i>Cập nhật PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-keyboard me-2"></i>Phân loại PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar me-2"></i>Ước tính rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Cập nhật rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Báo cáo</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Tra cứu thông tin</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Hướng dẫn sử dụng</a>
    </div>
    <!--sidebar end-->
  </div>
  <div class="content col-10"> Content
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60bf89e922.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  document.querySelector('#menu-toggle').onclick=e=>{
    var sidebar=document.querySelector('#sidebar');
    if(sidebar.style.display!=='none')
      sidebar.style.display='none';
    else
      sidebar.style.display='block';
  }
</script>
```

for your example add this script tag at the end of your html

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('#menu-toggle').onclick=e=>{
    var sidebar=document.querySelector('#sidebar');
    if(sidebar.style.display!=='none')
      sidebar.style.display='none';
    else
      sidebar.style.display='block';
  }
</script>
```

edit: my bad, there was a typo, try again

Comment: thankyou for your answer
I did as you said but nothing has changed 
can you give me more advice

Comment: incredible, thankyou so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to add popper js library and bootstrap 5.2 libraries to deal with javascript also With bootstrap docs I add more details to the run button. I hope this helps

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-2rNj2KJ+D8s1ceNasTIex6z4HWyOnEYLVC3FigGOmyQCZc2eBXKgOxQmo3oKLHyfcj53uz4QMsRCWNbLd32Q1g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Y8eGK92dzouwpROIppwr+0kPauu0qqtnzZZNEF8Pat5tuRNJxJXCkbQfJ0HlUG3y1HB3z18CSKmUo7i2zcPpg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Your code amend it also you can change button to keep consist design

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header row ">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div id="logo" class="pb-2 ps-2 pe-0 col-2">
      <img class="float-start py-2 ps-2 pe-2" src="assets/img/unknown.png">
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggler flex-shrink-0" id="menu-toggle">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-left py-4 pe-2"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="body row ">
  <div class="sidebar col-2 " id="sidebar">
    <!--sidebar start-->
    <div class="navbar-nav w-100">
      <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button"id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Admin
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">B action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-th me-2"></i>Cập nhật PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-keyboard me-2"></i>Phân loại PO</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar me-2"></i>Ước tính rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Cập nhật rebate</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Báo cáo</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Tra cứu thông tin</a>
      <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt me-2"></i>Hướng dẫn sử dụng</a>
    </div>
    <!--sidebar end-->
  </div>
  <div class="content col-10"> Content
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/60bf89e922.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  document.querySelector('#menu-toggle').onclick=e=>{
    var sidebar=document.querySelector('#sidebar');
    if(sidebar.style.display!=='none')
      sidebar.style.display='none';
    else
      sidebar.style.display='block';
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you can try [.offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/offcanvas/) in Bootstrap

Comment: A link-only answer is insufficient to meet the SO guidelines and is only acceptable as a comment (Note, that is not acceptable either to misuse other options as a workaround to bypass your account limitations).